# How to save two DataFrames to one file, one above other, in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two dataframes; `u` and `v`. Each of them contains the exact same large number of columns and rows (the index is a MultiIndex). I wish to save them to one `.txt` file using `.to_csv`, so that `u` is vertically above `v`.

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The key was to add `mode='a'` in the second iteration of `to.cv`

```
u.to_csv("test.txt", header = False, index = False, sep='\t')
v.to_csv("test.txt", **mode='a'**, header = False, index = False, sep='\t')
```